# Why isn't my reference TreeNode changing the nodes of my binary tree?

Tags: java, reference, binary-tree, treenode

I'm working on a BinarySearch program, and I'm working on the method that inserts the values into the tree.

However, when I run the code, the nodes of the root variable are not being changed with the reference variable current.

Why is this?

My code:

```
public boolean insert(E element) {
    return insert(element, root);

}

private boolean insert(E element, OrderedSet<E>.TreeNode current) {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new TreeNode(element);
        return true;
    }

    if (current.data.compareTo(element) == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {

        if (current.data.compareTo(element) > 0) {
            return insert(element, current);
        } else {
            current = current.right;
            return insert(element, current);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `current` is passed by value, not by reference. You can't assign a value to it and expect to get it back in the caller.

Comment: Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Java parameters are always passed by value. This is a bit confusing when the parameter is a *reference* variable. The thing to note is:

- Any assignment to a parameter is *not* going to be seen by callers, only inside the method body. This is true whether it's primitive or a reference (to an object).
- If the variable is a reference to a mutable object (that is, an object whose fields you can access and change either directly or by using a setter), then an assignment *to a field* is going to be seen by the caller.

So what can we do about the above program? Assuming you have access to the `TreeNode` object's `left` and `right` fields, you should change the method so that the `current` parameter always represents the *parent* node of any added node. This way, it will never be `null`, it will always be a real object. And in a real object, we can change fields!

So we start with the top method:

```
public boolean insert(E element) {
    if ( root == null ) {
        root = new TreeNode( element );
        return true;
    } else {
        return insert(element, root);
    }
}
```

If we have nothing in our tree as yet - the root is null - then we can't call our recursive method at all. As it stands, there is no "parent" node to pass. But in this situation, the proper thing to do is to set the `root` to the given element. So we create a new node, with the given element, and assign it to root. The next time, `root` will no longer be `null`!

If it wasn't null, we can pass it as the "parent" for the insertion. Either its content is equal to the new element (in which case the recursive method will return false), or the item will have to be inserted somewhere *under* it. So it is a good "parent".

Now the recursive method itself:

```
private boolean insert(E element, OrderedSet<E>.TreeNode current) {

    if (current.data.compareTo(element) == 0) {

        // The element is already in the tree, so we do not insert
        // anything, and we return false.

        return false;
    } else {

        if (current.data.compareTo(element) > 0) {

            // Smaller elements need to be inserted at the left

            if ( current.left == null ) {
                current.left = new TreeNode( element );
                return true;
            } else {
                return insert(element, current.left );
            }

        } else {

            // Bigger elements need to be inserted at the right

            if ( current.right == null ) {
                current.right = new TreeNode( element );
                return true;
            } else {
                return insert(element, current.right );
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Now, the code for each case (bigger and smaller) has become slightly more complicated:

```
            if ( current.left == null ) {
                current.left = new TreeNode( element );
                return true;
            } else {
                return insert(element, current.left );
            }
```

We are no longer allowed to pass a `null` to the next recursion step, because a `null` is not a proper "parent" and we won't be able to assign to its fields. So if the left branch is null, we can't recurse. But in this case, the appropriate action is to actually set the left node to our new element, because it *is* smaller than our current node. So we create a new node, set `current.left` to reference it, and now we have added something to the tree, we can return `true`.

But if the `left` node was not null, then either it will be equal to the given element or the given element will have to be set somewhere under it. So the left node is a good "parent" node, and we can call the recursion with it.

The same logic also applies to adding elements to the right.

Because we are assigning directly to `current.left` and `current.right`, which are *fields* of our given `current`, the result *will* be seen by the caller.